# If I have a speed, or acceleration(or both) of moving charged particle, how can I determ a radited photon's frequency?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

If I have a speed, or acceleration(or both) of moving charged particle, how can I determ a radited(by this particle) photon's frequency? And do I understand right, that the energy of photon(and frequency) will be decrease with r^2?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question:  No, the energy and frequency of the photon do not decrease as it travels.  Classically, the intensity (energy per time per area) of an electromagnetic wave decreases inversely proportionally to $r^2$, where $r$ is the distance from the source.  But if we were to surround a weak single-frequency light source with photon detectors, they would still detect photons at that same frequency regardless of how far away they were.  They'd just detect them less frequently:  the farther away the detector is, the more precisely the photon has to be "aimed" in order to hit it, and so fewer photons will hit a more distant detector.

As far as the frequency of the radiated photons:  this is a very hard problem that's usually reserved for classes at the graduate level.  The short answer is that there's a range of possible frequencies, not just a single frequency.  For example, for a charged particle moving in a circle,  most of the energy is radiated as photons with a frequency between about $0.1 f$ and $f$, where $f$ is the frequency at which the particle is going around the circle;  see the graph below.

[image]

If you're interested in learning more about the light emitted by moving charges, take a look at the Wikipedia articles on [synchrotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation) (from which the above graph is taken) and [brehmsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung);  but be aware that they're pretty heavy going.

Comment: *Intensity (energy per time per area) of an electromagnetic wave decreases* it means, that part of photons are absorbs by particles on its way? If there no particle, that can absorb photons, intensity wouldn't decrease, yes?

Comment: And, I think you are wrong. According to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction#Overview_of_the_fundamental_interactions table, the range, where the interraction propagetes is unlimeted(last column), as you said, but the power is depends on distance(pre-last column). I can say more - the Coulomb's law is **(q1*q2)/r^2**, that means, that the power will decrease, and it's not about intensity

Comment: @ArturKlochko:  I think you are confusing the ideas of *power* and *intensity*.  A source emitting a wave sends out a certain *power* (energy per time.)  But as this wave moves away from the source, it spreads out over a larger and larger area.  This means that the *intensity* (power per area, or energy per area per time) decreases.  So each photon carries a fixed amount of energy;  but they spread out over larger and larger areas as they move further away, which means that the number of photons *per area* (and therefore the intensity of the EM energy) decreases with distance.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I understood. But what about the Coulomb's law, that says, that the force dercreses with distance. As the second photoelectric effect law says, the intensity of light doesn't influence on the ability to tear off electrons. It means that, there is no matter how many photons(intensity) will be absorbed, if they haven't enough energy, the electrons will not come off. It means that the intensity doesn't influences on the force, and means that the force is the frequency, right? Then, it should depends on distance, according to Coulomb law, yes?